# The SO Android Tag Updated

Tags: discussion

I'm not certain when it was updated but the Android Tag on SO now lists AE for user-related questions. The tag's About page was also updated. This should help bring devs to the site for user-related issues!

See the updated answer here: [How to direct Android Devs on SO to the Android Enthusiast's Beta Site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69276/how-to-direct-android-devs-on-so-to-the-android-enthusiasts-beta-site/69807#69807)

Comment: I managed to get enough rep on the android tag on SO to make the change ;)

Comment: Good idea, I've added something similar to the SuperUser Android tag info http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android